# GitHub Actions: Failed to run android tests in emulator

Tags: android, continuous-integration, automated-tests, github-actions

So I've developed my android application and while doing so, I created plenty of androidTests that require an emulator or connected device to run. It runs perfectly in my local android studio when I call `.\gradlew connectedAndroidTest`, but in GitHub Actions when I download the emulator, it just does not launch and the job is stuck for an indefinite amount of time. Here's my most successful CI so far:

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "test-dev" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

env:
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: ./gradle-cache

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11

    - name: Grant execute permission for Gradle wrapper
      run: chmod +x gradlew

    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew assembleDebug

    - name: Run Android tests
      uses: reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2
      with:
        api-level: 29
        script: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

    - name: Upload test results
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: test-results
        path: app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/
```

The error is:

```
build  
Timeout waiting for emulator to boot.
```

I beg you, help me out with this. I feel like I'm getting crazier.

---

**UPDATE**

Error with the `macos-latest` runner:

[image: error]

Comment: You're using `ubuntu-latest` runner but https://github.com/ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner requires `macos-latest` to run the emulator in a VM. So, you need to configure your workflow accordingly.

Comment: Even after changing to macos-latest, it is still failing to restart: https://imgur.com/a/CKZHE6r

Comment: Looks like others are also facing similar [issues](https://github.com/ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner/issues) with this action. You might want to [create an issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner/issues/new/choose) with all the details specific to your use case.

Comment: Alright, will do!